# Missing } inserted. \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies

When I run the LaTeX code I got the following error message.

```
Missing } inserted. \end{thebibliography}
```

I have used the following code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfig,epsfig}
\newcommand{\subfig}{\subfloat}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=25mm,top=40mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{epsfig,theorem,amsmath,enumerate,amsfonts,xspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Time ...............

\include{introduction}

bibliography{references}             % References.
\bibliographystyle{jfm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We don't have your `introduction.tex` file, nor your `references.bib` file.  I would suggest working your way through https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/107497 so that we can copy and paste and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can not add the code of introduction and bibliography as it produces an error when posting it.

Comment: We need only the bib file ...